# Canvas won't show in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been learning HTML5 and got to the part on the "canvas" element. I tried to create my own little canvas and the stuff specified in the  Javascript doesn't appear.
Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas - One</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-one");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = "#990000";
    context.strokeRect(20, 30, 360, 240);
    context.fillRect("#990000")
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas-one" width="360" height="240" style="border:1px">
        <p>You don't support the 'canvas' element? Better get to fixing that.</p>
    </canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: `fillRect` expects totally different parameters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975416(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to put your canvas Javascript code at the very end of your HTML body:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas - One</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas-one" width="360" height="240" style="border:1px">
        <p>You don't support the 'canvas' element? Better get to fixing that.</p>
    </canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-one");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.strokeStyle = "#990000";
        context.strokeRect(20, 30, 360, 240);
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 360, 240);
    </script>
</body>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ken92/1/

You need to make sure that your DOM is loaded and this will ensure that your canvas initialization runs after the canvas element is added to the DOM.

I also fixed a bug with your call to `fillRect`. You had `context.fillRect("#990000")` which is incorrect. `fillRect` expects four parameters like so: 
`fillRect(x, y, w, h)`

Comment: this doesn't answer the question at all. OP has some errors in the code itself. (edit: better, but maybe talk about what needed to be changed in fillRect)

Comment: I didn't catch the error with the fillRect call. I fixed it. I'm not sure what the OP was going for with the fillRect call.

Comment: I think OP meant to change fillStyle before filling the rect. and it seems they want to fill the stroked area. `context.strokeStyle = a; context.fillStyle = b; context.rect(...); context.stroke(); context.fill();` but that is a guess.

Comment: One can only speculate I suppose until we get more information from the OP. I updated fillRect to fill the canvas width and height and I added a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas - One</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas-one" width="360" height="240" style="border:1px">
        <p>You don't support the 'canvas' element? Better get to fixing that.</p>
    </canvas>
</body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-one");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = "#990000";
    context.strokeRect(20, 30, 360, 240);
    contex.fillRect(20,20,150,100);
    </script>
```

Try this.

There are two mistakes in your code,

1. The given parameters in the fillRect() method. it should be like `context.fillRect(x,y,width,height);`
2. You put the plain script in the head, this not the reason for the current problem but the script runs before the canvas is created so you can't draw anything in canvas.
   solution is use the script in onload method or put it below the body tag.

Hope this helps.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle that may be helpfull: [Canvas](http://jsfiddle.net/kostisalex/nbA8X/)

where, the js code is loaded in the onLoad event and not earlier!

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-one");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.rect(20, 30, 360, 240);
context.fillStyle="#990000";
context.fill();
```

By using the **fill** method you have not to redefine the dimensions of the rect.

Answer (score -1):

That's the proper way.

Canvas is a child of window so the window must be loaded first.

You can use DOM ready, too.

```
window.onload = function(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas-one");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    context.strokeStyle = "#990000";
    context.strokeRect(20, 30, 360, 240);
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 360, 240)
}
```

Comment: You did not get the bug in the fillRect method

Comment: Sure, but anyway what I've written is true